# Do I weigh less after a shower?

Tags: weight-loss, body-measurements

Several times now I have weighed myself before and after a shower, and noticed that my scale thinks I weigh less after taking a shower -- something like a pound less.  Could that be right? Why would this happen?  Does a shower cause dehydration, maybe?  Which weight should I believe?

Comment: Not sure this is even on topic, but... While showering you might lose weight from a few sources; skin surface stuff (dead skin cells, hairs, oils, microbes, dirt, etc), sweat, and urine. Just a few things off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

You will weigh less after a hot shower, and, you hit the nail on the head; sweating and dehydration. You're losing water weight in a hot shower and depending on how long and how hot your shower is, this number can differ.

It's similar to how MMA fighters sit in a sauna before weigh-in in order to make their weight class.

The important part here is this weight loss is incredibly **temporary**. You'll regain this weight after drinking water or even just getting your body back to room temperature.

You should aim to weigh yourself at a consistent time and in a consistent circumstance, maybe weekly. Your body will fluctuate weight throughout the day for many reasons.